# How can i remove the user input added paragraph automatically after 2 seconds in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i just learned how to create a to-do list in java script and as a personal project i wanted to use the information i learned in to-do app making by creating a tell your secret website which like the

```js
const mytext = document.getElementById('mytext');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const items = document.getElementById('items');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const paragraph = document.createElement('p');
  paragraph.classList.add("item");
  paragraph.innerText = mytext.value;
  items.appendChild(paragraph);
  mytext.value = '';
 
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: rgb(231, 237, 241);
}
main {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}
h2 {
  color: rgb(71, 80, 102);
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.myform {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#btn {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  white-space: pre-line;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(184, 182, 182);
  color: rgb(35, 70, 136);
}
#btn:active {
  color: rgb(48, 95, 182);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px grey;
}

#mytext {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  padding: 7px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px rgb(200, 207, 212);
  outline: none;
}
.items {
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: rgb(61, 61, 60);
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=MedievalSharp&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200;300;400;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<main>
  <h2>Write Your Secret</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <form class="myform" action="">
      <textarea name="text" id="mytext" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Write Whatever You Wish"></textarea>
      <button id="btn">S
        h
        a
        r
        e</button>
    </form>
    <div class="items" id="items"></div>
  </div>
  
</main>

  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

to-do app user writes something in the box (his/her secret) and the secret is displayed on the screen but
this is what i need:
i need the displayed paragraph to be removed automatically after 2 second like the secret vanishes 2 second after you write it.even better if it vanishes slowly like the ink vanishes in harry potter movie in tom riddle diary but that's not important i just want to remove the secret after 2 seconds first and then worry about the style that it vanishes.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and leave just the code relevant to what you're asking? There's too much "noise" as it is.

Comment: You can use setTimeout in the click event listener. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp
Try some code by yourself and update the question when stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the simple addition of this code:

```
setTimeout(() => paragraph.classList.add("hidden"), 2000)
```

Which adds the class "hidden" after 2 seconds it will do what you want. You could make class `hidden` do anything, such as just set the visibility to `hidden` but you can also do transition effects like the one you deswcribe:

```
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

If using a transition like above you can also add this line to remove the element when the transition completes

```
paragraph.addEventListener('transitionend',() => paragraph.remove())
```

Live example below

```js
const mytext = document.getElementById('mytext');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const items = document.getElementById('items');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const paragraph = document.createElement('p');
  paragraph.classList.add("item");
  paragraph.innerText = mytext.value;
  items.appendChild(paragraph);
  mytext.value = '';

  paragraph.addEventListener('transitionend',() => paragraph.remove())
  setTimeout(() => paragraph.classList.add("hidden"), 2000)
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: rgb(231, 237, 241);
}
main {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}
h2 {
  color: rgb(71, 80, 102);
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.myform {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#btn {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  white-space: pre-line;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(184, 182, 182);
  color: rgb(35, 70, 136);
}
#btn:active {
  color: rgb(48, 95, 182);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px grey;
}

#mytext {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  padding: 7px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px rgb(200, 207, 212);
  outline: none;
}
.items {
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: rgb(61, 61, 60);
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h2>Write Your Secret</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <form class="myform" action="">
      <textarea name="text" id="mytext" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Write Whatever You Wish"></textarea>
      <button id="btn">S
        h
        a
        r
        e</button>
    </form>
    <div class="items" id="items"></div>
  </div>
  
</main>
```

Comment: dear Jamiec thank you very much for your answer and although it gives me what i want there is still one problem and that is the written input just gets hidden and not removed.is there any way i can remove it so it would not remain in storage ? imagine an actual website where people come to write that i cant have millions of hidden user inputs. Im not trying to publish this website but for the educational reasons i need to remove user inputs.

Comment: thank you very much dear Jamiec problem solved.

Comment: @AshkanNaeimipoor word of advice, avoid the use of "dear" - it doesnt mean what you think it does in western English  ;) But you're very welcome for the help.

Answer (score -2):

```
 const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
 const items = document.getElementById('items');

 const clearInput = () => {
    setInterval(function(){mytext.value = ''; }, 2000);
 }

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const paragraph = document.createElement('p');
  paragraph.classList.add("item");
  paragraph.innerText = mytext.value;
  items.appendChild(paragraph);
  mytext.value = ''; 
});

clearInput()
```